# Solr ClusteringComponent Carrot2 : ClassNotFoundException

Tags: solr, carrot2

I get the following error when I try to run Solr with the Clustering Component.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/carrot2/core/ControllerFactory
    at org.apache.solr.handler.clustering.carrot2.CarrotClusteringEngine.<init>(CarrotClusteringEngine.java:101)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
```

I have included the apache-solr-clustering.3.2.0.jar using the

```
<lib dir="/usr/local/jetty/solr/lib/" regex="apache-solr-clustering-.*\.jar" />
```

But it looks like I am missing some carrot2 jar files. I cannot find any documentation to indicate what else I am missing or what I am doing wrong.

Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to include the jars from `contrib/clustering/lib/`